# Traefik redirect issue for different origin

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a spring boot web app (JSP) running inside a container. I have used traefik as a reverse proxy and also for load balancing.
Currently, my application is accessible when I directly access it using the traefik URL ([www.xyz.com/domain/test/index.html](http://www.xyz.com/domain/test/index.html)).

But I have a different gateway application([www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)) and when I open this URL from the gateway, if I submit the UI form to create any data like employee records, I get redirected to the login page.

What I observed is, the URL is changing from [www.abc.com/domain/employee/create](http://www.abc.com/domain/employee/create) to [www.xyz.com/login.html](http://www.xyz.com/login.html)